# AKS 1.22.2 cluster Ingress configuration not working with Azure Application gateway

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I have created helm charts for deploying the kubernetes objects. I have created services, ingress and deployments for hosting my microservices. I created application gateway and I'm trying to use application gateway as public load balancer for my cluster. But my ingress not pointing to application gateway load balancer and ip address also showing empty.

please find my configuration values below.

Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: demo-microservice
            port:
              number: 80
```

Service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.name }}"
   labels:
    app: "{{ .Values.name }}"
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: "{{ .Values.name }}"
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

**Note : Also I have enabled Ingress controller and mapped my application gateway while creating the cluster.**

[image]

But IP address is not got assigned. My azure application gateway loadbalancer also not redirecting to my application. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Anyone please assist me on this

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORoDH.png)

Reference
[aks ingress address is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729586/aks-ingress-address-is-empty)

Comment: I am confused why do you have `ingress.class` annotation on a `Service`, its supposed to be only on `Ingress`. Also the Service you have shown is type `LoadBalancer` is same as `demo-microservice`  service which your ingress points to?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @YK1. I have updated my service.yaml.  Yes I have to point demo-microservice and other microservices later to my Ingress.

Comment: I have a similar problem. 
There are `E0221 11:41:34.895822       1 reflector.go:138] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.21.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource (get ingresses.extensions)
` log messages which indicate a version conflict. 

`kubectl describe pod   ingress-appgw-deployment-` shows that `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-application-gateway/kubernetes-ingress:1.5.0-rc1` is installed. The rc1 has a bug causeing this.

It seems the addon deploys the wrong version of the ingress ctrl

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the cluster is configured with the Application Gateway AddOn:

```
--[appgw-name][--appgw-subnet-cidr][--appgw-subnet-id]
```

Comment: Yes Cluster is configured with the Application Gateway Addon . I confirmed via portal and also via powershell  - Output The ingress-appgw addon is already enabled for this managed cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need give to ingress controller identity permission to AppGateway,you need assign role Contributor/Reader, and Managed Identity Operator role on AppGateway identity.